# How to link my static .a library to a c Xcode(10.2.1) project

Tags: xcode, static

I have my own static c library eg. mylibrary.a , I have used it on a bunch of school projects from the terminal but I want to now use it with an Xcode(10.2.1) command line project for testing other projects.

I have tried putting the header file and .a file in the projects directory, adding the .a in the build phase menu under "link binary with libraries". I also tried linking it under "Other linker flags" by typing out my library's directory path. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's old but maybe will work for you:

- Go to your Project's Build Phases
- Click on the "+" under "Link Binary With Libraries" to add a new library. Then click on the "Add Other" button.
- Navigate to the static library file (.a) and add it.

[https://www.chilkatsoft.com/xcode-link-static-lib](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/xcode-link-static-lib.asp)

And then you should add your directory `Build Settings` > `Library Search Path`

**Note:** Not the full path, just the directory.